# Is there a way to modify the styles created under a Media query that is using media features with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, media-queries

I have two css media queries with the features, portrait and landscape.  I would like to modify these using javascript so I can dynamically change the styles inside these based on variables being passed to the page.  I know I can use document.styleSheets[x].rules[x] to modify the css but I'm not sure how I can modify just the styles under the specific media queries.

Here is my current code:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    #Header {
        background-color: #000;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #Main .row ul li {
        width: 110px;
        height: 145px;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 2px 4px 2px 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: relative;
        display:table-cell;
        float:left;
    }

    #Main .row ul li img {
        border: 0;
        width: 86px;
        height: 86px;
        padding: 12;
    }

}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    #Header {
        background-color: #000;
        height: 45px;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #Main .row ul li {
        width: 115px;
        height: 110px;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 2px 4px 2px 0px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: relative;
        display:table-cell;
        float:left;
    }

    #Main .row ul li img {
        border: 0;
        width: 66px;
        height: 66px;
        padding: 8px;
    }
}
```

I would need to change the styles separately between the two orientations.

This page gets me part of the way there with how to specify media query's but not how I can specify media features inside of those media query's.
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstylesheets

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an exact answer to my question, but found three different ways of accomplishing the end goal in (I think) a more flexible way.

First:
Get rid of css media features and media queries completely. Instead use javascript to detect device orientation. Then change the css directly when the orientation changes using document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]; to change each style each time.

http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change
http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript

Second:
Is a variation of the first.  I could create two different style sheets.  One for portrait and one for landscape.  Then using the Javascript method of orientation detection I could switch between style sheets as needed.

http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change
https://www.inetsolution.com/turnleft/post/CSS-Style-Switcher-A-quick-and-dirty-how-to.aspx

Third:
In my situation I only needed to dynamically create the media queries one time.  So the third option is to create the media queries using javascript in the first place.

http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets